# Not able to recieve messages from discord in discord.py

Tags: python, discord.py

Hello i was learning to create a discord bot.
But i m facing an issue i.e. i m not getting any messages from in .py file from discord i tried giving all the roles and changing the intents.

Here is my code.
I creates 3 files
main
bot
responses

```
bot.py
import discord
import responses


# Send messages
async def send_message(message, user_message, is_private):
    try:
        response = responses.handle_response(user_message)
        await message.author.send(response) if is_private else await message.channel.send(response)

    except Exception as e:
        print(e)


def run_discord_bot():
    TOKEN = 'mytoken'
    client = discord.Client(intents=discord.Intents.default())

    @client.event
    async def on_ready():
        print(f'{client.user} is now running!')

    @client.event
    async def on_member_join(member):
        await member.create_dm()
        await member.dm_channel.send(
            f'Hi {member.name}, welcome to my Discord server!'
        )

    @client.event
    async def on_message(message):
        # Make sure bot doesn't get stuck in an infinite loop
        print(message.content)
        print(message.channel)
        if message.author == client.user:
            return

        # Get data about the user
        username = str(message.author)
        user_message = str(message.content)
        channel = str(message.channel)
        # Debug printing
        # await message.channel.send('hi')
        print(f"{username} said: '{user_message}' ({channel})")
        # If the user message contains a '?' in front of the text, it becomes a private message
        if user_message[0] == '':
            print(' ') 
        if user_message[0] == '?':
            user_message = user_message[1:]  # [1:] Removes the '?'
            await send_message(message, user_message, is_private=True)
        else:
            await send_message(message, user_message, is_private=False)

    # Remember to run your bot with your personal TOKEN
    client.run(TOKEN)
```

```
`responses.py`
import random


def handle_response(message) -> str:
    p_message = message.lower()
    if p_message == 'hello':
        return 'Hey there!'

    if p_message == 'roll':
        return str(random.randint(1, 6))

    if p_message == '!help':
        return "`This is a help message that you can modify.`"
```

```
`main.py`
import bot

if __name__ == '__main__':
    bot.run_discord_bot()
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/48kqi.png)
here is the output of my code.
you can see before channel name there is empty line thats where the content should come.

Comment: Please trim your code to make it easier to find your problem. Follow these guidelines to create a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Answer (score 0):

You need to have `message_content` intent, and this does not include in `discord.Intents.default()`. You could do

```py
intents = discord.Intents.default()
intents.message_content = True

client = discord.Client(intents=intents)
```

And don't forget to turn `message_content` permission on at discord developer portal.
See more info [docs](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/stable/api.html?highlight=intent#discord.Intents.message_content)